# Java Sockets : How to send multiple files from client based on an event to server

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a program wherein client needs to monitor the creation of files in a specific folder and send them as they are created to the server.Server should always be in listening mode and save these files with the same name in the specified folder on the server.For now,i am trying to achieve this on the same m/c.How do i achieve this via socket?

I was able to monitor the creation of files in the folder at the client and send them.At the receiver,i was only able to receive one file.After that i was getting a FileNotFoundException at the server.

Client code

```
Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 5991);  
        System.out.println("Connecting.........");

        Path faxFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Tushar Yadav\\Music\\src\\");
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        boolean valid = true;
        do {

            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

            for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);

                    File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tushar Yadav\\Music\\src\\"+fileName);

                    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();  
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

                    dos.writeUTF(fileName);

                    dos.writeInt((int) myFile.length());

                    int filesize = (int) myFile.length();
                    byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];

                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile.toString());  
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  

                    int count; 
                    while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }   

                    dos.flush(); 

                }
            }
            valid = watchKey.reset();

        }while (valid);
```

Server code

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5991);
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        in = clientSocket.getInputStream();  
        clientData = new DataInputStream(in); 
        clientBuff = new BufferedInputStream(in); 

        while(true){

            System.out.println("Starting...");  

            String fileName = clientData.readUTF();     

            System.out.println("filename : "+fileName);

            int fileSize = clientData.read();

            System.out.println("filesize is "+fileSize);

            len=fileSize;

            System.out.println("C:\\Users\\Tushar Yadav\\Music\\dest\\"+fileName);

            output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Tushar Yadav\\Music\\dest\\"+fileName);

            dos=new DataOutputStream(output);
            bos=new BufferedOutputStream(output);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  

            bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 

            while (len > 0 && (smblen = clientData.read(buffer)) > 0) { 
                dos.write(buffer, 0, smblen); 
                len = len - smblen;
                dos.flush();
            }  
            dos.close();  

        }
```

I expect the server to wait for client to send another file as soon as it is created at the client side but i am getting a filenotfound exception soon after the receiver has received and saved the first file.

Also,one observation is that at the server side,i was seeing this line `System.out.println("filename : "+fileName);` and subsequent lines getting executed twice until the exception pops up inspite of only creating(and inherently sending) one file at the client.

Following are the logs for the server code:-

```
Starting...
filename : New Text Document.txt
filesize is 0
C:\Users\Tushar Yadav\Music\dest\New Text Document.txt
Starting...
filename : 
filesize is 0
C:\Users\Tushar Yadav\Music\dest\
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Tushar Yadav\Music\dest (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at test.Server.main(Server.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the client, you are writing the file size with `writeInt()`, but in the server you are reading it with `read()`. You should be using `readInt()`. This would throw everything off, since `read()` is only reading the first byte of the 4-byte integer length; then you don't read any data because you think the length is 0; then when you try to read the 2nd file's name, you're out of position and reading an empty string, which causes the error you're seeing. BTW it's probably more proper to use `writeLong()` and `readLong()`, since that's the return type of `File.length()`, but that's up to you especially if you're only using smaller files.

There also seems to be something off with how you're using the `DataOutputStream dos` and `BufferedOutputStream bos`, both of which wrap the same `FileOutputStream output`. You are first writing the full uninitialized buffer to the file via `bos` (only some of which might actually be written, since it's buffered); then you are again reading and writing the actual file data via `dos`, which will append to what was previously written to `output`. Maybe you meant something like `dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(output))`, which would give you the benefits of both. But you still don't want to write the whole uninitialized buffer before the read loop like you've done.

Also, since you're only using `write()`, you could probably directly use `output.write()` without the fancy DataOutputStream. The BufferedOutputStream is useful as an optimization if you want to avoid frequent small writes to the disk, but it's not necessary, especially since there's some inherent buffering in the way you're reading/writing 1Kb chunks.